# Transform data set in Excel or Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, transform

I have data in the following format:
[image: Raw Data]

And I want to transform it into the following format in either Excel or Google Sheets:
[image: Desired Format]

Any suggestions on how to complete this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [pivot table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) in Excel. I do not get exactly the same layout, but it comes close. [image]